# How to Verify if item from one list exists in any of another 2 lists

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, foreach

I have a Method like below .

```
public void Method(List<string> testingValues, IList<IWebElement> Element, IList<IWebElement> Element2)
{
    // verify if testing values available in element or element2 list
}
```

How can i write the code which will verify values from testingvalues  exists into list Element or Element2 ?

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
public bool Method(List<string> testingValues, IList<IWebElement> Element, IList<IWebElement> Element2)
{
     return testingValues.All(item => Element.Any(x => x.Text==item)
                                    ||Element2.Any(y => y.Text==item));
}
```

This method will return true, if all the values that are in `testingValues` are contained in either the `Element` or `Element2`. Otherwise, it will return false.

Comment: Hi @Christos, I m getting error for All, Any as below .

'System.Collections.Generic.IList<OpenQA.Selenium.IWebElement>' does not contain a definition for 'Any' and no extension method 'Any' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<OpenQA.Selenium.IWebElement>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) 

Same for All.

Comment: Wouldn't be better to join two lists first And then use one `Any`? I think it would be much faster

Comment: Have you included the `System.Linq`, `using System.Linq;`

Comment: @Christos  Sorry i thought i have added it . its not showing any error . now how can i get the index for it. Like for Element and Element2

Comment: I have updated as below u said now i need to get the index once element found . 

     public void Method3(List<string> testingValues, IList<IWebElement> Element, IList<IWebElement> Element2)
        {
          if (testingValues.All(item => Element.Any(x => x.Text == item) || Element2.Any(y => y.Text == item)))
            {

            }

            else
            {
                Assert.Fail();
            }
         
        }

Comment: @M.kazem Akhgary - I need to ge the index from list so join wont help

Comment: @vic Please state exactly what are you looking for. An input and an expected output. Thanks